# Using Metaio SDK on Android

Tags: java, android, metaio

I wanted to use the Metaio SDK free version for a project. I had an account but now I get a message saying that my account has expired. On the website there´s no way to register a new account in order to get a free app signature.

Is there any way I can get a free sdk app signature in order to start working? Is it possible to use the docs Examples signature just to get my app working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a metaio account, contact metaio support at contact(at)metaio.com. Yes, there is still someone . but just 
till the end of april or beginning of june.

Past year, Metaio had released a license signature generator which could be downloaded from their portal , if you had a dev account. 
So try writing them and kindly ask if they could help you.

But, I have to say that you will probably get warnings from the Google Play store , if you publish a metaio SDK app. Concerning SSL issues.

Good luck.